# Moment is showing wrong date in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, momentjs

I'm using moment to convert my JSON date into normal date format but I got 13 days previous date from correct date.

```
var dt = Moment.utc('2020-01-15T00:00:00').format('d MMM YYYY');
console.log(dt); // console value: 3 Jan 2020
```

Comment: You're supposed to do some (or better [a lot of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)) research before asking a question. A quick look in the docs would have solve the riddle -> https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`d` is the format for day of week (0-6). You want `D` or `DD` for day of month.

[Moment docs for format options](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Answer (score 0):

Acc to https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/  d while formatting in moment is for day of the week that is (0-6) 
so in your case it is showing as 3rd day of the week